# Learning QTP question

Tags: discussion

So we now have this question [Good Beginner eLearning Training Videos & Tutorials for HP QTP?][1]

Before all the spammers roll in, I think it would be nice to have a great, high quality ***protected*** and community wiki post of where to go to learn QTP.

Someone who knows QTP should put it together ahead of time, and post both the question and answer.

The idea is that we could add some value to this area instead of a deluge of "Look at my blog" posts.

Thoughts ?

Comment: Is QTP more well-known or LoadRunner?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a fantastic idea, Bruce. I'm not familiar with QTP myself, or I'd volunteer, but I'm sure there's plenty of folks here who could do this.

My vote is yes, do it.

Answer (score 1):

I know QTP and I am working in Test Automation field from past 10 years, I recently thought the same and started my blog where I will write code for issues which I faced and I think it might help other. I researched a lot and found several websites with QTP and other tools training material as well as video tutorials. This baffled me, because there are so many websites/ blogs then why more. I asked this question of software testing club website and got some motivations.

Oh !!! After writing above paragraph I saw the dates, you've asked this around a year back. So any updates so far ?